# What is the formula for plotting out this graph?

Tags: python, math, formula

What are the formulas for the R G B sinewaves? They all start the same but then offset slightly as they progress.

[image: RGB wavelengths]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: How would I form similar curves in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally followed [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/amplitude-period-frequency-phase-shift.html) page and used Paint to measure necessary variables

[image]

```python
# For Blue
A =  0.5
B =  2*pi/0.328
C = -0.08
D =  0.5
Blue(x) = 0.5 * sin(2*pi/0.328 * (x - 0.08)) + 0.5

# For Green
A =  0.5
B =  2*pi/0.382
C = -0.095
D =  0.5
Green(x) = 0.5 * sin(2*pi/0.382 * (x - 0.095)) + 0.5

# For Red
A =  0.5
B =  2*pi/0.5
C = -0.12
D =  0.5
Red(x) = 0.5 * sin(2*pi/0.5 * (x - 0.12)) + 0.5
```

When I plotted this functions the result was very similar to your image
[image]